# A condition evaluates to signed or unsigned integer?

Tags: c, conditional-statements, language-lawyer

We know that a condition in C, for example `a > b`, results in either 0 or 1. If we would like to utilize this `0`/`1` value directly in expression, e.g. `1 - (a > b)`, should we assume that it is signed or unsigned (as it can make a difference in expressions)? What does standard say about this?

Comment: try test `(1 > 0) > -1` and `(unsigned)(1 > 0) > -1`

Comment: Yes, Thanks. We can test this. Just wanted to know if it is specified in standard.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The type of the result of all relational operators is `int`:

> #### C11 §6.5.8 Relational operators
>
> Each of the operators `<` (less than), `>` (greater than), `<=` (less than or equal to), and `>=` (greater than or equal to) shall yield `1` if the specified relation is true and `0` if it is false. **The result has type int.**

So the type of `1 - (a > b)` is also `int`, a signed type.

Comment: Same for "*6.5.9 Equality operators*".

Answer (score 5):

The standard is clear. All relational operators (including equality and not equality) evaluate to 0 or 1, which are `int` types.

`a > b` will evaluate to 1 if `a` is bigger than `b`, and 0 otherwise.

`1 - (a > b)` therefore is an expression with type `int`.

Comment: Can you please share the standard text corresponding to this if you have the reference?

Comment: Concerning " There are no Boolean types in C;" --> C does have a "standard unsigned integer type" `_Bool` that can only have the value of 0 or 1.  Sound like a boolean type to me.  The presence of a boolean type in C still does not change that a conditionals result type is `int`.

Answer (score -1):

In the the result of a condition is always an int. Not so clear are the values for the boolean `true` and `false`. In the c89 standard it is only clear that false is equal to zero whereas `true` is just defined as a value different from zero. So in a old C89 system you would define true and false as follows:

```
#define FALSE (0)
#define TRUE !(FALSE)
```

However if true is always 1 and false always 0 depends on the compiler, because `true` and `false` is not defined by the C89 standard. So you can't rely on that the result (`true`) of a comparison is always 1, because it might be any int value different from 0.

This is the reason why boolean comparisons to `true` should be avoided, instead a comparison to `false` should be preferred.

The C99 standard introduced the type `_Bool`. In this standard `true` is defined as 1 and `false` is defined as 0. A C99 compliant compiler should not have other values for `true` as result of a condition. But internally it's still a signed int. But to be sure the specification of the compiler should be read, because if the compiler does not fully implement the C99 standard it still might be that the result of `true` is not 1.

Comment: Please note: `!0 != 1`

Comment: That's false. True is NOT 'always 1', true is 'not equal zero' in each compiler. This allows for example the loops like `for(i=5; i; --i){...}` or `while(*d++=*s++);` (K&R `strcpy`, AFAIR), also `if(value){...}` etc.

Comment: I never said that true is 'always 1'. I said that true is any value different from zero.

Comment: @chux You're right my answer might be a bit misleading... What I meant is the value for `true`. That it is always an int is clear to me. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @alk: Your statement is wrong. The theory of sets includes the 1 as part of the set "!0". Indeed the result of "!0 != 1" is false.

Comment: Everything I wanted to say that evereybody should be very careful in assuming that `true` is always 1, because this assumption is a pitfall.

Comment: All non-zero values are "truthy", but the operators which report truthiness never yield any truthy value other than 1.